# Tableau Union Joins - Can you un-merge automatically merged fields?

Tags: tableau-api

I am attempting to union join 2 tables in my Microsoft NAV data source within Tableau.  However, I have two field named "No." that do not contain the same data.

When I apply a union join, Tableau automatically merges these fields and I cannot un-merge them.

Is there a way to un-merge these fields?

Or is there a way of doing a manual union join?

I have tried renaming the field before dragging the second table into the worksheet  however I can see that the "Remote Field Name" still remains the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to let Tableau merge the fields and then use the generated fields to distinguish between them.

When you perform a Union in Tableau, it adds a few fields to your data source so you can tell which data rows came from which tables. The most useful in your case is called [Table Name]. So when you build your visualizations, you can use the [Table Name] field to know how to interpret the [No.] field.

If that is awkward, you can create 2 calculated fields to represent only those [No.] values that have the same role. For example, define [No. Type 1] as `if [Table Name] = “Table 1” then [No.] end`. And define, [No. Type 2] similarly. Then you can hide the original [No.] field.

These new fields will only have values for the appropriate data rows, and will be null otherwise. Aggregate functions like SUM(), AVG() etc ignore nulls, so you can use those fields as measures easily.

If you want to use a calculation in a JOIN clause, say after making a UNION, then first specify the tables (or unions of tables) to join, then when you click on the Venn diagram to specify the join keys, and then select either the left or right list of fields --> look at the bottom of the list in small print to either create or edit your Join Calculation.

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for this - very useful.  I have created a calculated field that pulls through the correct information from both fields.  However, I now need to join this to another table within NAV.  When I attempt to define the join clause, I cannot see my calculated field in the available fields to join on.  The data combined to create my new calculated field is the only common factor between the current 2 tables I have union joined and the new one I wish to connect to using a normal join.  Do you know of a way to get round this?  Thanks again.

Comment: What Tableau version?

Comment: Version 2018.1.5

Comment: I updated the answer to address your question. See the last paragraph. Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you find the response helpful, the nice thing to do is accept and upvote the answer.